# Cannot set width of div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

jQuery seems to have no problems when setting the styles on my div, just when it comes to width, it won't apply.

```js
var $carouselWidth = 200;
$("div").css({
  'margin-left': -40,
  'width': $carouselWidth,
  'visibility': 'visible'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background: black; height: 100px; width: 100px;"></div>
```

This seems to work in this preview, but on my website, the everything else gets applied but the width.

Whats even more strange is that if I check it using `$('div').width()` or `$('div').css("width")` it will output `200`, even though the element in the canvas has no such width applied.

---

EDIT:

ok, so in lieu of peoples comments about posting the appropriate code, all that I can do to alter the OP is to ensure that the version of jquery is the same. Other than that, I cannot reproduce the error except to point you guys to the website which hosts the code. If you open up the console, and use jquery to query the element `$('#fws_5a8c80107cce2')` and try to alter the width, it will not work. no matter which `x` method i try to use as per the answers provided.

link: 
http://www.leadingdc.com/buttercream/weddings/

hope this helps.

---

Had to edit the above again because I provided the wrong selector. Its correct now.

---

Nevermind, I dont know what it is, but there seems to be something inconsistent going on when the script loads. I was able to successfully manipulate it from the browser a few times, but it isnt happening 100% of the times. Moreover, in my code (which resembles the snippet), it just will not apply at all.

Comment: Since it *does* work in the Snippet, we'll need more code to troubleshoot.

Comment: if your variable on the server is being set as a string and not an integer the units may need to be appended

Comment: I actually have already tried the string method to no avail. Any other suggestions by chance?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("div").width(100).height(200);
```

Comment: I've tried this too and it still does not alter the width although it will return the correct value when trying to get the width using that method `.width()`

Comment: Try this.. It will work fine.. $("div").css("height", 123);

Answer (score 0):

You were missing the Units on your measurements
even though jQuery defaults to Pixels i have seen issues with units needing to be declared

I have found when setting the variable on the server-side sometimes it needs to be explicitly cast as an `int` otherwise the units will need to be appended

```js
var $carouselWidth = 200;
$("div").css({
  'margin-left': '-40px',
  'width': $carouselWidth+'px',
  'visibility': 'visible'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background: black; height: 100px; width: 100px;"></div>
```

Comment: From the jQuery .css() docs: _When a number is passed as the value, jQuery will convert it to a string and add px to the end of that string. If the property requires units other than px, convert the value to a string and add the appropriate units before calling the method._

Comment: I understand what the docs say, i only know that i have seen issues where it does not correctly apply. Take that for what is ts worth.

Comment: Plus, the code the OP posted works, as seen in the snippet in their own question. He needs to post an example of the problem he has; not one that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:-

```js
var $carouselWidth = 400;
$("div").css({'margin-left': "-40px",
      'width': $carouselWidth+'px',
      'visibility': 'visible'
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background: black; height: 100px; width: 100px;"></div>
```

Comment: From the jQuery .css() docs: _When a number is passed as the value, jQuery will convert it to a string and add px to the end of that string. If the property requires units other than px, convert the value to a string and add the appropriate units before calling the method._

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it is working find..

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<div id="h" style="background-color:black;">

</div>

<script>
    $("#h").css("height",222);

  $("#h").css("width",222);

</script> 

</body>

</html>
```